# Get the OU of the current Logged in User PowerShell Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am creating a logon script that welcomes users by saying their name and the OU that they're apart of.

Code:

```
    Import-Module activedirectory
    $user = (Get-WMIObject -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem).Username
    $disName = Get-ADUser -Filter * | Select DistinguishedName
    $split = $disName.Split(',')

    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
    $Output = $wshell.Popup("Welcome, $user", 0, "OU, $split[1]", 0x1)
```

The error is with the `$disName`. When I output just `$disName`, I get this:

```
DistinguishedName  
{}  
{}  
{} etc.
```

I am not sure if it is outputting this because I am on the DC or I am not correctly grabbing the OU.

I was under the impression the `DistinguishedName` was `CN=Test User,OU=Tech,OU=DUsers`.

Otherwise I run this code and the only thing that is printed out for `$split[1]` is `[1]`

And I was also getting an error with the split method, but I think that`s because there was nothing to split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your existing code, the simplest things to do for the output box to display the proper values is to use the ["$( )" PowerShell operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html) to wrap around the double quote enclosed variables within `$output` (i.e. `$($user)` and `$($split[1])`). Also use `$env:USERNAME` as the value for `$user`, and use another `Split('=')[1]` to parse out the `OU=` from the `$split` variable.

### PowerShell

```
Import-Module activedirectory
$user = $env:USERNAME;
$disName = (Get-ADUser $user).DistinguishedName;
$split = $disName.Split(',');

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$Output = $wshell.Popup("Welcome, $($user)", 0, "OU, $($split[1].Split('=')[1])", 0x1);
```

**Output**

[image]

---

#### Bonus PowerShell

Here's some additional bonus PowerShell that is relevant that you might find helpful related to this task. I tested all posted logic against Active Directory confirming the output(s) as well.

```
Get-ADUser $env:USERNAME -Properties * | Select CanonicalName, DistinguishedName | FL;
(Get-ADUser $env:USERNAME).DistinguishedName;
(Get-ADUser $env:USERNAME -Properties *).CanonicalName;
((Get-ADUser $env:USERNAME).DistinguishedName).Split(",")[1];
((Get-ADUser $env:USERNAME -Properties *).CanonicalName -split "/")[-2];
```

### Supporting Resources

- [PowerShell Operators $( ) @( ) :: &](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html)

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate your answer

Answer (score 0):

I am nowhere near an ADDS environment right now, but what you're doing is more simple than the effort you are showing, as well as being a really common thing to do with many examples all over the web, in books, and on Youtube.

Anyway, why just use PowerShell directly? Meaning, why not just do something like this (Native cmdlets and .Net namespace)?

```
# $MemberOU = ((Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -like $env:USERNAME}).DistinguishedName -split ',') -match 'OU=' -replace 'OU='
$MemberOU = ('CN=Tom Smith,OU=IT,DC=SomeDomain,DC=Com' -split ',') -match 'OU=' -replace 'OU='
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("You are a member of this organizational unit: $MemberOU", "Welcome, $env:USERNAME", 'OK', 'Information')
```